# Suggest any tutorial for Ajax Zend Paginator

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, jquery

Can any one suggest any good tutorial or any set of code which help to implement a pagination using Zend paginator and php ajax?

Does the paginator is submitting each time on clicking the next and previous?

By ajax do we can prevent this each time request?

I am able to find some pagination tutorials and ajax tutorial separately.

But if anyone can suggest any good combined tutorial , that will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really great video tutorial series by [**integral30**](http://www.youtube.com/user/integral30) on youtube

Starting with basic [**Zend Framework 1.9 tutorial 11: Zend_Paginator part 1**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4fujot7Xlc&feature=related)

and extending this with [**Zend Framework 1.9 tutorial 14: ajax requests part 1**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xrw8TP62-XU&feature=BFa&list=PLC7FDFC7E0F370A02&index=4) for ajax pagination.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Blatant self promotion - http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2011/03/awesome-pagination-with-zf-paginator-ajaxcontext-and-the-html5-history-api/